# Delete leaderboard data before submitting app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I have a game that uses leaderboards that I have not yet submitted for app review and publishing on iTunes Connect yet.  I want to delete the test scores that I've been using with my sandbox Game Center players before going live.

Looking at instructions and other screenshots on the web, my leaderboard doesn't look right in iTunes Connect.

[image]

There is no method to view the leaderboard from iTunes Connect, and no method for me to delete the scores to reset it before publishing.  How do I go about doing that?

Is this normal?  Also, should the status say "Not live" at this time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer.  The screenshots and tutorials I was looking at must have been slightly out of date.  In order to delete the test data, you need to click the "More" button in the top right, and then select "Delete test data" from the dropdown.

I'm still not entirely sure about the status saying "Not live", but I suspect it becomes live as soon as your app does.  I will try to remember to update this when I publish and find out.